# How can I copy result from Calculator.app to the clipboard using AppleScript

Tags: applescript, calculator, clipboard

How do I copy the result of the Calculator.app including decimals.

By defaults is selected, so if you just do a CMD+C it copies it into your clipboard. I got this code from @jweaks

```
set the clipboard to {?????}
```

I tried entering many different options but I don't know what I should put.

Comment: @jweaks I don't know if you could help me with this one ;o)

Comment: Your question in the title already is answered by other 2 users. I want only add that the **result (real) of Calculator.app when GUI scripting** is stored in the clipboard in the **text form**. So, to get the real and to work with it further, you should coerce the clipboard contents back to the real: **set theResult to the clipboard as real**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I copy the result of the Calculator.app including decimals.
> `set the clipboard to {?????}`

As you already know **⌘C** can do it, however, if you want to use a `set clipboard to` *method*, then here is one way to go about it:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
if not running of application "Calculator" then return

tell application "System Events" to ¬
    set the clipboard to ¬
        (get the value of ¬
            static text 1 of ¬
            group 1 of ¬
            window 1 of ¬
            process "Calculator")
```

**Notes:**

- Does not require **Calculator** to be *frontmost*.
- Does not require the use of `keystroke` or `key code` to accomplish the task.
- Can set the *value* to a *variable* instead of *the clipboard*, if wanting to process it in a different manner.

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Catalina** and **macOS Monterey** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

In testing, the **Replies** *pane* in **Script Editor** returned, e.g.,:

```applescript
tell application "System Events"
    get value of static text 1 of group 1 of window 1 of process "Calculator"
    --> "6200.549407114624506"
    set the clipboard to "6200.549407114624506"
end tell
```

Then when pasting into a *document* it pasted as: `6200.549407114624506`

---

### **Update to address comments**

To address the ensuing comments by sebseb under my answer and specifically…

> Is it possible to run the script every time I hit enter on Calculator? then copy the result.

Basic *vanilla* **AppleScript** is not that intelligent and does not have the ability in of and by itself to understand what one is doing in **Calculator** and know when one has pressed the **enter** *key* to then place the *result* on *the clipboard*.

One would have to use an intermediary, an *application* like [**Hammerspoon**](https://www.hammerspoon.org), where it can wait for the **Calculator** *application* being activated/deactivated or its *window* being *focused/unfocused* to then *enabled/disable* trapping the **enter** *key* being pressed on the **keyboard** to then run the *script* to perform an action to *calculate* the *result* by pressing the **=** *key* then copy the *result* to *the clipboard*.

This works because pressing the **=** *key* in **Calculator** is equivalent to pressing the **enter** *key*, thus enabling trapping the **enter** *key* to perform the necessary actions using **AppleScript**. It quite possibly can be done without using **AppleScript** and just **Lua**, the *language* used by **Hammerspoon** and its **API**. However, since I already use various **AppleScript** *scripts* in conjunction with **Hammerspoon** and can easily recycle some existing *code* I'll present an addendum to the original answer using both methods in **Hammerspoon**.

The following *example* **Lua** *code* and **API** of **Hammerspoon** is placed in the `~/.hammerspoon/init.lua` *file*.:

```lua
    --  Create a hotkey used to trap the enter key and disable it.
    --  It will then be enabled/disabled as Calculator is focused/unfocused
    --  When enabled and the enter key is pressed it runs the AppleScript script.

local applicationCalculatorEnterHotkey = hs.hotkey.bind({}, "return", function()
    local asFile = "/.hammerspoon/Scripts/CalculatorResultToClipboard.applescript"
    local ok, status = hs.osascript.applescriptFromFile(os.getenv("HOME") .. asFile)
    if not ok then              
        msg = "An error occurred running the CalculatorResultToClipboard script."
        hs.notify.new({title="Hammerspoon", informativeText=msg}):send()            
    end
end)
applicationCalculatorEnterHotkey:disable()


    --  One of two methods of watching Calculator.
    --  
    --  The other is below this one and commented out.

    --  Initialize a Calculator window filter.

local CalculatorWindowFilter = hs.window.filter.new("Calculator")

    --  Subscribe to when the Calculator window is focused/unfocused.

CalculatorWindowFilter:subscribe(hs.window.filter.windowFocused, function()
        --  Enable hotkey when Calculator is focused.
    applicationCalculatorEnterHotkey:enable()
end)
CalculatorWindowFilter:subscribe(hs.window.filter.windowUnfocused, function()
        --  Disable hotkey when Calculator is unfocused.
    applicationCalculatorEnterHotkey:disable()
end)


        --  Alternate method to wait for Calculator and enable/disable the hotkey.
        --  
        --  Uncomment below method and comment the above method to test between them. Adding the 
        --  multiple line opening '--[[' and closing '--]]' to above method and removed from below,
        --  leaving 'local CalculatorWindowFilter = hs.window.filter.new("Calculator")' uncommented.

--[[    

function applicationCalculatorWatcher(appName, eventType, appObject)
    if (eventType == hs.application.watcher.activated) then
        if (appName == "Calculator") then
                --  Enable hotkey when Calculator is activated.
            applicationCalculatorEnterHotkey:enable()
        end
    end
    if (eventType == hs.application.watcher.deactivated) then
        if (appName == "Calculator") then
                --  Disable hotkey when Calculator is deactivated.
            applicationCalculatorEnterHotkey:disable()
        end
    end
end
appCalculatorWatcher = hs.application.watcher.new(applicationCalculatorWatcher)
appCalculatorWatcher:start()
-- appCalculatorwWatcher:stop()

--]]
```

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* is used in conjunction with **Hammerspoon** and is saved as **CalculatorResultToClipboard.applescript** in `~/.hammerspoon/Scripts/`, and you'll need to create the *hierarchical folder structure*.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

One can use either:

```applescript
tell application "Calculator" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    key code 24
    delay 0.5
    set the theResult to the value of static text 1 of group 1 of window 1 of process "Calculator"
end tell
set the clipboard to theResult
```

Or:

```applescript
tell application "Calculator" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    key code 24
    delay 0.5
    key code 8 using command down
end tell
```

To accomplish the task.

An alternate option, as previously mentioned, is to forgo the use of **AppleScript** and use the following *example* **Lua** *code*:

```lua
local applicationCalculatorEnterHotkey = hs.hotkey.bind({}, "return", function()
        --  Press the '=' key to finish the calculation.
    hs.eventtap.keyStroke({}, "=")
        --  Copy the result to the clipboard.
    hs.eventtap.keyStroke({"cmd"}, "C")
end)
applicationCalculatorEnterHotkey:disable()
```

This *function* would be used instead of the same *function* further above. It replaces the execution of the **AppleScript** *script* with *keystrokes* generated by **Hammerspoon** to accomplish the same tasks, while using the remaining *example* **Lua** *code* and the **API** of **Hammerspoon** already presented.

**Notes:**

With the *example* **Lua** *code*, as coded, the behavior of pressing the **enter** *key* is only trapped and modified to trigger the *example* **AppleScript** *code*, or if using the alternate option send **Hammerspoon** *keystrokes*, while **Calculator** has focus. The **enter** *key* should work normally in all other *applications*.

See my other **Hammerspoon** related answers for instructions to install it and utilize the information contained herein.

One in particle is:

- [A: How can I make preview stop wrapping around when paging?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/420872/how-can-i-make-preview-stop-wrapping-around-when-paging/420879?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C31.4896#420879)

If using **Script Editor**, the *example* **AppleScript** *code* is saved as **Text** in the **File Format:** *pop-up menu* in the **Save** *dialog box*.

The *example* **Lua** *code* and **API** of **Hammerspoon** and **AppleScript** *code*, shown directly above, were tested respectively with **Hammerspoon** and **Script Editor** under **macOS Mojave** and **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

Comment: @sebseb, What version of **macOS** are you running?

Comment: @sebseb, I just test the _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ in my answer under **macOS Mojave** 10.14.6 and it does indeed place the result of the **Calculator** _application_ on _the clipboard_.

Comment: In you question you explicitly state "How do I copy the result of the Calculator.app including decimals." The _result_ is what is left after a _calculation_ is made, so why would you run the _script_  before making the _calculation_!? RE: "But I would need to get the result. Without having to run the script every time." -- Sorry, but that's not the way _scripting_ usually works. I'd suggest you just use the built-in _keyboard shortcut_ **⌘C** to copy the _result_ to _the clipboard_ as needed.

Comment: RE: "Why can't the script be running all the time? every time I do a calculation copy the result to clipboard." --  Basic _vanilla_ **AppleScript** is not that intelligent and does not have the ability in of and by itself to understand what you are doing in **Calculator** and know when you are at a _result_ you what placed on _the clipboard_.

Comment: Is it possible to run the script every time I hit enter on Calculator? then copy the result.

Comment: @sebseb, RE: "Is it possible to run the script every time I hit enter on Calculator? then copy the result." -- As I previous said "Basic _vanilla_ **AppleScript** is not that intelligent and does not have the ability in of an by itself …", so you would have to use an intermediary, an _app_ like [**Hammerspoon**](https://www.hammerspoon.org), where it waits for **Calculator** being activated/deactivated and then enabled/disable trapping the **enter** _key_ on the keyboard being pressed to then run the _script_ to copy the _result_ to _the clipboard_.

Comment: @sebseb, The _script_ would also have to perform the function of the **enter** _key_ since its being trapped by **Hammerspoon**. It could `key code 24` to perform the _calculation_ and then copy it to _the clipboard_. Note that while this _method_ can and does work, you have to keep in mind that as **Calculator** is either activated/deactivated or focused/unfocused that enabling/disabling trapping the **enter** _key_ is not necessarily instantaneous, it takes a number of milliseconds to a second for it to occur, depending on how much activity the **CPU** is currently processing system wide.

Comment: @sebseb, RE: "Is it possible to run the script every time I hit enter on Calculator? --  I have update my answer to address this. See the **Update to address comments** _section_ in my answer, thanks.

Comment: Wow, amazing job. Thanks so much. A few questions, HS works, Hello World, works. When I hit enter in the Calculator HS says: An error occurred running: the CalculatorResultToClipboard script
I used: ~/.hammerspoon/init.lua file
and the first script saved in ~/.hammerspoon/Scripts/CalculatorResultToClipboard.applescript

Comment: Your code works, the auto copy to works. The first 2 times works fine, after that I need to hit enter twice, to get the calculation to work. Very strange. Do you have the same thing at your end?

Comment: @sebseb, RE: "Your code works, the auto copy to works. The first 2 times works fine, after that I need to hit enter twice, to get the calculation to work." -- In my initial testing I did not have any issue, however, I probably didn't run it multiple times in a row as if in production use. Testing now I can replicate the _bug_ but not sure why it's happening. That said, I did stop using the original `local applicationCalculatorEnterHotkey = hs.hotkey.bind({}, "return", function()` for the one that only use **Hammerspoon** _keystrokes_ and not **AppleScript** and it didn't fail in my testing.

Comment: Thanks so much, it all works perfectly, like a Swiss clock !!

Answer (score 0):

Calculator.app doesn't have an AppleScript dictionary.

You have to script the UI with `System Events`

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Calculator"
        set frontmost to true
        keystroke "c" using command down
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks, @vadian, it works, but only works once. How can I do so that every time I use the calculator it's copying the result ?