# How to use AppleScript with Calculator.app to Automatically select the number of Decimals

Tags: applescript, calculator, automator

Every time I enter a number in Calculator.app I need to go the top menu and select:
View >> Decimal Places >> [0 , 15] And choose the number of decimals.

Is there a way to make an AppleScript that will automatically do so, based on the number I entered?

My input ways are:

1. by pasting the number
2. by typing the number

For the pasting part, if you PASTE a number ending in 0, Calculator.app won't show the 0, so it will show one decimal less than the reality. I don't know if this could be also overcome.

Example, if you paste: 12.30 it will show 12.3
if you type: 12.30 it will show 12.30

Comment: In **Calculator**, when pasting e.g. `12.30` it does indeed show as `12.3`, however no matter what you set **Calculator** > **View** > **Decimal Places** to it still does not show the `0`. So why is this such a big deal?

Comment: @user3439894 thanks again, it's mostly for the next calculation. Ex.: 12.3 / 1.01 = 12.18 , It will choose 1 decimal, so you'll see 12.2 instead, which is not correct.

Comment: RE: "so you'll see 12.2 instead" --  No, I see: `12.178217821782178`

Comment: that's what I do now and I don't feel the tip of my fingers. So, I decided to automate as much as possible. And I need it to run all the time while calculator is in use. The decimal selector should run at start and the copy result at the end.

Comment: You see 12.178217821782178 because you have many decimals, but since I entered 12.30, it should select 2 decimals (not more not less). So, I should get 12.18

Comment: Note that the menu setting just rounds the result shown - you can enter more digits, and internally it still uses the highest precision.  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the addendum to my answer to your other question [How can I copy result from Calculator.app to the clipboard using AppleScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69947468/how-can-i-copy-result-from-calculator-app-to-the-clipboard-using-applescript), here is a way the trap **⌘V** in **Calculator** and set **Calculator** > **View** > **Decimal Places** to the number of decimal places of the number on *the clipboard*.

### What the *example* **AppleScript** *code* does:

When pressing **⌘V** in **Calculator** the contents of *the clipboard* is set to a *variable* and if it contains a *decimal point* it sets the **Calculator** > **View** > **Decimal Places** *menu* to the number of *decimal places* in the *number*, then *keystrokes* the *number* into **Calculator**.  Note that *keystroking* the *number* would probably not require you to set the number of *decimal places*, however I'll leave that up to you to decide.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
set theNumberToType to the clipboard as text

if theNumberToType contains "." then
    set theNumberOfDecimalPlaces to count characters ((offset of "." in theNumberToType) + 1) thru -1 of theNumberToType
    if theNumberOfDecimalPlaces is greater than 15 then set theNumberOfDecimalPlaces to 15
else
    set theNumberOfDecimalPlaces to -1
end if

tell application "Calculator" to activate

tell application "System Events"
    if theNumberOfDecimalPlaces is greater than -1 then
        click (first menu item of menu 1 of menu item "Decimal Places" of menu 1 of menu bar item "View" of menu bar 1 of process "Calculator" whose name is theNumberOfDecimalPlaces)
    end if
    delay 0.1
    keystroke theNumberToType
end tell
```

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* above is saved as **CalculatorSetDecimalPlaces.applescript** in: `~/.hammerspoon/Scripts/`, like in my other answer to your other question.

*Example* **Lua** *code*:

```lua
    --  Create a hotkey used to trap the command v shortcut and disable it.
    --  It will then be enabled/disabled as Calculator is focused/unfocused.
    --  When enabled and command v is pressed it runs the AppleScript script.

local applicationCalculatorCommandVHotkey = hs.hotkey.bind({"cmd"}, "V", function()
    local asFile = "/.hammerspoon/Scripts/CalculatorSetDecimalPlaces.applescript"
    local ok, status = hs.osascript.applescriptFromFile(os.getenv("HOME") .. asFile)
    if not ok then              
        msg = "An error occurred running the CalculatorResultToClipboard script."
        hs.notify.new({title="Hammerspoon", informativeText=msg}):send()            
    end
end)
applicationCalculatorCommandVHotkey:disable()


    --  Add the following two line respectively before or after the lines
    --  applicationCalculatorEnterHotkey:enable()
    --  applicationCalculatorEnterHotkey:disable()
    --  in either of the two methods presented in my other answer.

applicationCalculatorCommandVHotkey:enable()

applicationCalculatorCommandVHotkey:disable()
```

**Notes:**

With the *example* **Lua** *code*, as coded, the behavior of the **⌘V** *keyboard shortcut* is only trapped and modified to trigger the *example* **AppleScript** *code* while **Calculator** has focus. The **⌘V** *keyboard shortcut* should work normally in all other *applications*.

The *example* **Lua** *code* above is added to the `~/.hammerspoon/init.lua` *file* from my other answer to your other question.

The *example* **Lua** *code* and **API**'s of **Hammerspoon** and **AppleScript** *code*, shown above, were tested respectively with **Hammerspoon** and **Script Editor** under **macOS Mojave** and **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

---

### Update using only **Lua** without **AppleScript**

The following *example* **Lua** *code* eliminates the use of **AppleScript** from both this answer and the *code* in the other answer to your other related question.

Overwriting the existing *code*, copy and paste this into your `~/.hammerspoon/init.lua` *file*, save it and run **Reload Config** from the **Hammerspoon** *menu* on the **menu bar**.

I have performed all the various actions and calculations discussed in the comments and had no issues occur with this new *code*. Hopefully this will eliminate any issues you were having.

This should also run faster now that it does have to process **AppleScript** *code* as well.

Note that as coded it is not automatically reloading the configuration file as that just should not be necessary.

```lua
    --  Create a hotkey used to trap the enter key and disable it.
    --  It will then be enabled/disabled as Calculator is focused/unfocused
    --  When enabled and the enter key is pressed it presses = then command C.

local applicationCalculatorEnterHotkey = hs.hotkey.bind({}, "return", function()
        --  Press the '=' key to finish the calculation.
    hs.eventtap.keyStroke({}, "=")
        --  Copy the result to the clipboard.
    hs.eventtap.keyStroke({"cmd"}, "C")
end)
applicationCalculatorEnterHotkey:disable()


    --  Create a hotkey used to trap the command v shortcut and disable it.
    --  It will then be enabled/disabled as Calculator is focused/unfocused.
    --  When enabled and command v is pressed it runs the Lua code within.

local applicationCalculatorCommandVHotkey = hs.hotkey.bind({"cmd"}, "V", function()
        --  Get the number copied to the clipboard.
    local theNumberToType = hs.pasteboard.readString()
        --  See if there is a decimal in the number
        --  and if so how many decimal places it has.
    local l = string.len(theNumberToType)
    local s, e = string.find(theNumberToType, "%.")
    if s == nil then
         theNumberOfDecimalPlaces = -1
    elseif l - s > 15 then
         theNumberOfDecimalPlaces = 15
    else
         theNumberOfDecimalPlaces = l - s
    end
        --  Set the number of decimal places to show.
    if theNumberOfDecimalPlaces > -1 then
        local calculator = hs.appfinder.appFromName("Calculator")
        local vdpn = {"View", "Decimal Places", theNumberOfDecimalPlaces}
        calculator:selectMenuItem(vdpn)
    end
        --  Type the number into Calculator.
    hs.eventtap.keyStrokes(theNumberToType)
end)
applicationCalculatorCommandVHotkey:disable()


    --  One of two methods of watching Calculator.
    --  
    --  The other is below this one and commented out.

    --  Initialize a Calculator window filter.

local CalculatorWindowFilter = hs.window.filter.new("Calculator")

    --  Subscribe to when the Calculator window is focused/unfocused.

CalculatorWindowFilter:subscribe(hs.window.filter.windowFocused, function()
        --  Enable hotkeys when Calculator is focused.
    applicationCalculatorCommandVHotkey:enable()
    applicationCalculatorEnterHotkey:enable()
end)
CalculatorWindowFilter:subscribe(hs.window.filter.windowUnfocused, function()
        --  Disable hotkeys when Calculator is unfocused.
    applicationCalculatorCommandVHotkey:disable()
    applicationCalculatorEnterHotkey:disable()
end)


    --  Alternate method to wait for Calculator and enable/disable the hotkey.
    --  
    --  Uncomment below method and comment the above method to test between them.
    --  The opening '--[[' and closing '--]]' and removed from below added to above.

--[[    

function applicationCalculatorWatcher(appName, eventType, appObject)
    if (eventType == hs.application.watcher.activated) then
        if (appName == "Calculator") then
                --  Enable hotkeys when Calculator is activated.
            applicationCalculatorCommandVHotkey:enable()                
            applicationCalculatorEnterHotkey:enable()
        end
    end
    if (eventType == hs.application.watcher.deactivated) then
        if (appName == "Calculator") then
             -- Disable hotkeys when Calculator is deactivated.
            applicationCalculatorCommandVHotkey:disable()            
            applicationCalculatorEnterHotkey:disable()
        end
    end
end
appCalculatorWatcher = hs.application.watcher.new(applicationCalculatorWatcher)
appCalculatorWatcher:start()
-- appCalculatorwWatcher:stop()

--]]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239257/discussion-on-answer-by-user3439894-how-to-use-applescript-with-calculator-app-t).

Comment: @sebseb, Please see and implement the new _example_ **Lua** _code_ in the **Update using only Lua without AppleScript** _section_ of the answer.

Comment: Wow, it flies, it's so fast and no glitches what's so ever. Everything works perfectly. I'm so happy ;o) I was playing around with the old codes and I didn't even manage to make it copy the result. Thanks a lot