# What's the hot key for TAB in .lua? hammerspoon?

Tags: lua, hammerspoon

I would like to do an <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> after the COPY:

```
hs.eventtap.keyStroke({"cmd"}, "C")
```

In this code [SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69954193/how-to-use-applescript-with-calculator-app-to-automatically-select-the-number-of) by user: @user3439894

So, normally it would be something like this, as suggested by @Oka:

```
hs.eventtap.keyStroke({"alt"}, "tab")
```

and this:

```
hs.eventtap.keyStroke({"alt"}, {"tab"})
```

But this doesn't work. Or probably I'm placing it in the wrong place.

And I don't know how to use this suggestions, by Oka:

```
pushkeycode(L, kVK_Tab, "tab");
```

SOLVED by @user3439894 in this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70335380/how-to-use-applescript-or-lua-to-do-an-alt-tab-after-results-on-the-calculator)

Comment: @user3439894, do you know the TAB hot key? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In [this issue](https://github.com/Hammerspoon/hammerspoon/issues/2065), the correct string to use is said to be `"tab"`.

After some digging around in the [keycodes](https://github.com/Hammerspoon/hammerspoon/tree/master/extensions/keycodes) extension source code, we can confirm this.

From [`keycodes.lua`](https://github.com/Hammerspoon/hammerspoon/blob/master/extensions/keycodes/keycodes.lua#L67):

```
--- hs.keycodes.map
--- Constant
--- A mapping from string representation of a key to its keycode, and vice versa.
--- For example: keycodes[1] == "s", and keycodes["s"] == 1, and so on.
--- This is primarily used by the hs.eventtap and hs.hotkey extensions.
---
--- Valid strings are any single-character string, or any of the following strings:
---
---     f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, f11, f12, f13, f14, f15,
---     f16, f17, f18, f19, f20, pad., pad*, pad+, pad/, pad-, pad=,
---     pad0, pad1, pad2, pad3, pad4, pad5, pad6, pad7, pad8, pad9,
---     padclear, padenter, return, tab, space, delete, escape, help,
---     home, pageup, forwarddelete, end, pagedown, left, right, down, up,
---     shift, rightshift, cmd, rightcmd, alt, rightalt, ctrl, rightctrl,
---     capslock, fn
```

We can see this set up in the `keycodes_cachemap` function in [`libkeycodes.m`](https://github.com/Hammerspoon/hammerspoon/blob/master/extensions/keycodes/libkeycodes.m#L157):

```
pushkeycode(L, kVK_Tab, "tab");
```

Comment: Thanks @Oka, but for some reason it doesn't work: hs.eventtap.keyStroke({"alt"}, "tab")