# How to use AppleScript or Lua to do an ALT + TAB after results on the Calculator.app

Tags: lua, applescript, automator, hammerspoon

I use the Calculator.app, and after hitting the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, I would like it to automatically do an <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> to go to the previous App I was using: Excel or Firefox or Chrome, ... you name it.

I have the same question for just .lua, but if it can't be done with .lua I'd like to do it with AppleScript or with the Automator.

[What's the hot key for TAB in .lua? hammerspoon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70142261/whats-the-hot-key-for-tab-in-hammerspoon)

**UPDATE:**

As user3439894 says, <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> works fine.

But in my end, the <kbd>TAB</kbd> is not released, therefore, I keeps on showing all the open apps. So, I tried to put a <kbd>RETURN</kbd> as of the documentation. I also tried <kbd>ENTER</kbd> , but non of them work.

```
hs.eventtap.keyStroke({"cmd"}, "tab")
hs.eventtap.keyStroke({"return"})
-- hs.eventtap.keyStroke({"enter"})
```

Comment: Do you mean **⌘-Tab** as **⌥-Tab** is not the **App Switcher** _keyboard shortcut_.

Comment: This works for me: `hs.eventtap.keyStroke({"cmd"}, "tab")`

Comment: Thanks user3439894 , you are right, it's cmd and not tab. But how do I release the tab? I noticed it works, but keeps on showing all the open apps. It's like the tab key is not released. I don't understand what's the " App Switcher " you mention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your are using this in conjunction of one of the answers I gave you back in mid November regarding **Calculator**, then the modified **Lua** *code* below works for me to switch to the previous *application* when pressing the <kbd>enter</kbd> *key* while in **Calculator**.

*Example* **Lua** *code*:

```lua
    --  Create a hotkey used to trap the enter key and disable it.
    --  It will then be enabled/disabled as Calculator is focused/unfocused
    --  When enabled and the enter key is pressed it presses = then command C.

applicationCalculatorEnterHotkey = hs.hotkey.bind({}, "return", function()
        --  Press the '=' key to finish the calculation.
    hs.eventtap.keyStroke({}, "=")
        --  Copy the result to the clipboard.
    hs.eventtap.keyStroke({"cmd"}, "C")
        --  Bring up the App Switcher.
    hs.eventtap.keyStroke({"cmd"}, "tab")
        --  Act on the selected App in the App Switcher.
        --  This works in testing with Calculator, however
        --  may not work in other applications.
    hs.eventtap.keyStroke({}, "=")  
end)
applicationCalculatorEnterHotkey:disable()
```

**Notes:**

I've added two `hs.eventtap.keyStroke` to the original *code* with comments.

Executing `hs.eventtap.keyStroke({"cmd"}, "tab")` in the **Console** **Hammerspoon** does automatically switch to the previous *application* without showing the **App Switcher**, however when used in the `applicationCalculatorEnterHotkey` *function* it shows the **App Switcher** as if **⌘-Tab** has been pressed and the **⌘** *key* not released. This may be a bug, not sure as not enough testing/research into the issue was done as the obvious solution would be to follow up with programmatically pressing the **enter** *key*, however that can not be done from within the `applicationCalculatorEnterHotkey` *function* because it is already trapping the **enter** *key* in **Calculator**.

In this particular use case, however this is where `hs.eventtap.keyStroke({}, "=")` is used to act as if the **enter** *key* had been pressed again and is unique to **Calculator**.

Comment: Thanks, @user3439894 that worked perfectly, please let me know how can I send you a paypal donation, via chat mode.

Comment: I just did so @user3439894. You could also answer the other question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70142261/whats-the-hot-key-for-tab-in-lua-hammerspoon

..., with a link to this one.
And if you change your mind, just let me know, because I learnt so much and all this will save me a lot of time and clicks/moves. Thanks again